# How to write and extract maths function to phpMyAdmin

Tags: database, math, phpmyadmin

I want to write **subscript , superscript and Arithmetical fractions** in database and extract it to quiz **to show perfectly**,

how can I do?

I am using **collection - utf8-general-ci**

Comment: How are you rendering the quiz? Is it shown in a web page, desktop application (what language?), mobile app, or some other means? This is more a functionality of how you're displaying it than the database itself; the database will store whatever you chose to put in but your application will have to know how to handle the superscript and subscript. MvG is right about the fact that many of these already have such functionality built in, but without more information about how you're displaying it we can't guess what your program will be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want Unicode subscripts like x₁₂, HTML subscripts like *x*<sub>12</sub> or LaTeX subscripts like `x_{12}` which you can feed to e.g. [KaTeX](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/)? Depending on which of these, you can choose the appropriate format and then just store that string. If you might want to extend the database to more complicated functions in the future, I'd suggest going with LaTeX notation.

Comment: KateX support all browser?